# How to get when an item is added without using item's events

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, event-receivers

We are using a replication program that when it's adding new items to the destination server, item's events aren't triggering. Yet, I need to know when a new  (replicated) item is been inserted into a list (of the destination server).

Is there a workaround?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways you can do this

1. Event Receivers - The most elegant way (I am not sure why this is not working for you)
2. Workflows - This can be set to trigger for new items
3. Create a custom form for New Item create - And use code to let you know that a new item is inserted

Comment: Event Receivers and Workflows can't work because events aren't firing when an item is added through replication. Cannot create a custom form because the item is created on the source server and the replicated item doesn't fire any events.